# Parse HTML table by column using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I need to parse a HTML table using BeautifulSoup. The table has 2 columns in which the 2nd column is of datatype number. I need to find a total for all the numbers in Column2. I am able to extract the table data but I am stuck at that point. Can someone please help.

Here is the code so far.

```
import urllib
from BeautifulSoup import *
url = raw_input('Enter URL- ')
html = urllib.urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
table = soup.find("table")  
for row in table.findAll('tr'):   
    row_text = list()             
    for item in row.findAll('td'):  
        text = item.text.strip()
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't post a url to the page, I can't test it, but you can use the `findNext` method to find the second `td` tag.  Then add all the results up of that tag.  Here is a start:

```
total = 0
for row in table.findAll('tr'):
    item = row.find('td'):  
    numberValue = item.findNext('td').get_text()
    total = total + int(numberValue)
```

Your url points to a homework page.  On looking at the homework, it would be easier to directly get the number based on the `span` tag.  Here is what I would use to access the tag:

```
for row in table.findAll("span",attrs={"class":"comments"}):
```

This should be a helpful hint.

Comment: Thanks @dstudeba for your answer. Unfortunately its not working for me yet. Here is the url for you to test the result:  http://pr4e.dr-chuck.com/tsugi/mod/python-data/data/comments_194448.html

Comment: Thanks @dstudeba that helped.